# Change input background-color with styled-component

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

How can one change an input background color when used as a styled component?

```
const MyInput = styled.input`
background-color: "blue";
`
```

Comment: You are mixing notations. The values in css are not wrapper with quotes. And styled-components uses the css standard notation, so should be `blue` instead of `"blue"`.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
const MyInput = styled.input`
background: blue;
`
```